# How to rotate hexagone in this code with css/jquery?

Tags: html, css

I'm using this code for hexagon, and trying to rotate this. css transform rotation is working but after that shape gone. Also I am trying to add border:5px to hexagon...here it is the code:

```
#hexagon 
{
    width: 100px; 
    height: 55px; 
    background: red; 
    position: relative; 
    transform:rotate(30deg); 
    -ms-transform:rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#hexagon:before 
{ 
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: -25px; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 0;
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-bottom: 25px solid red; 
} 

#hexagon:after 
{ 
    content: ""; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: -25px; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-right: 50px solid transparent; 
    border-top: 25px solid red; 
}

<div id="hexagon">
</div>
```

Help!

Answer (score 0):

With only CSS you can make it rotate by adding this to #hexagon

```
animation: hexa360 3s infinite linear;
```

And then

```
@keyframes hexa360 {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

So it should look like this :

```
#hexagon 
{
    width: 100px; 
    height: 55px; 
    background: red; 
    position: relative; 
    animation: hexa360 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes hexa360 {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

No change to before and after. You'll need browser prefix too.